# Concatenenar bytes o string por medio de puerto serial por python

Tags: python, concatenación, pyserial

intento hacer una comunicacion por medio de un puerto serial rs232, los datos lo obtengo de un modulo de wago 752-652. Para que me muestre una cadena de caracteres en un solo renglón son 3 valores separados por comas. El resultado lo necesito en un sola cadena de caracteres, ¿Cual es el error o sugerencia que me puedan dar?

este es el codigo que tengo:

```
    '-------------------- LIBRERIAS IMPORTADAS --------------------'

import time as tm
import serial

'-------------------- Programa principal --------------------'

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Se asigna el puerto 
    ser=serial.Serial('COM6','19200',stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    tm.sleep(2)

    if ser.isOpen():
        print('PUERTO SERIE CONECTADO')
        print('Estado del puerto serial',ser.isOpen())
        print('Nombre del dispositico conectado',ser.name)
        print('\n#############################################################################################\n')

    else:
        print('Puerto serie fallo')

    try:
        num=0

        while True:
        
            getBytes=b''
            
            count=ser.inWaiting()
        
            if count>0:
                data=ser.read(count)
                                               

                if data!=count:
                    num+=1
                    print(data)
                    print(num)
                    data=getBytes

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('puerto serie cerrado')  
        if ser!=None:
            ser.close()
```

El resultado que me da me lo muestra de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `f"{data.decode()}{num}"` o `data.decode() + str(num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wago 752-652 es solo una interfaz; falta el detalle esencial del sensor conectado y el formato con que se reciben los datos, lo que es vital para saber cuando tenemos la tripleta completa. En vista, voy a considerar que los datos vienen terminados con un `\r\n`.

La forma correcta de leer datos que no arriban completos es:

- Leer lo que haya.
- Juntarlo con la lectura anterior.
- Examinar el resultado total: si hay una línea completa, procesarla.

En concreto, se hace así:

```
linea = ""
while True:
    count = ser.inWaiting()
    if count > 0:
        data = ser.read(count).decode()
        linea += data
        if '\n' in linea:
            completa, linea = linea.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
            print(f"Linea completa: {completa}")
```

Fijate que en una sola lectura podemos tener trozos de dos tripletas sucesivas, por lo que hay que partir la `linea`, retornando en `completa` una tripleta completa y dejando en `linea` el comienzo incomplento de la siguiente tripleta.

#### Demo

*Arduino*

Ejecuta un ciclo infinito enviando tripletas por partes.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("1.15635276,");
  delay(300);
  Serial.print("1.14780676,");
  delay(300);
  Serial.println("0.00854599");
  delay(1000);
}
```

*Python*

```
import time as tm
import serial

'-------------------- Programa principal --------------------'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Se asigna el puerto 
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', '19200', stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    tm.sleep(2)

    if ser.isOpen():
        print('PUERTO SERIE CONECTADO')
        print('Estado del puerto serial', ser.isOpen())
        print('Nombre del dispositico conectado', ser.name)
        print('\n#############################################################################################\n')
    else:
        print('Puerto serie fallo')

    try:
        linea = ""
        while True:
            count = ser.inWaiting()
            if count > 0:
                data = ser.read(count).decode()
                linea += data
                if '\n' in linea:
                    completa, linea = linea.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
                    print(f"Linea completa: {completa}")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('puerto serie cerrado')
        if ser != None:
            ser.close()
```

produce:

```
PUERTO SERIE CONECTADO
Estado del puerto serial True
Nombre del dispositico conectado /dev/ttyUSB0

#############################################################################################

Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
Linea completa: 1.15635276,1.14780676,0.00854599
puerto serie cerrado
```

Comment: ¿Es posible que el objeto `ser` proporcione el método `readline()`? Eso simplificaría la implementación

Comment: @abulafia. No se si los datos vengan terminados con `\n`. El OP no da el formato completo de la comunicación. Use `\n` de ejemplo sólo por simplicidad. El `readline()` tiene el problema de bloquear hasta salir por timeout si no encuentra el `\n` y te puede devolver un string inmensamente grande. En cambio, con `read()` puedes hacer el código asíncrono, lo que es una ventaja en app de comunicación: puedes procesar mientras esperas.